# Two mass spring system - Correct ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to study a two mass-spring system, considering also the gravity forces. I have this system:
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iCSj.png)

So, I took the equations from this site: http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/CoupledSpringMassSystem

And I put the masses in a vertical position and I considered these equations:
$$ m_1 x_1'' = m_1 g + k_2\cdot (x_2 - x_1 - L_2) - k_1\cdot(x_1-L_1) - c_1x_1'  $$
$$ m_2 x_2'' = m_2 g + F - k_2\cdot (x_2 - x_1 - L_2) - c_2 x_2'  $$

With L1 and L2 the lengths of the springs when subjected to no external forces, and F the applied force.

Then I plot the positions:
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxHdi.png)

And I think it's weird because, in reality, the two masses must continuously going down, but as you can see in the graph, they are oscillating around their initial position.

What did I forgot? Thank you!

Comment: 1) either wait longer or 2) make your $c_1, c_2$ larger so that the system will die down quicker (the $c_1, c_2$ controls how fast energy is leaving  the system)

Comment: $F\,\hat{y}$ is a Constant Force such that it can be equilibrated by the springs. Indeed, you can write a simpler equation if you rewrite your equations around the equilibrium positions. Oscillations occurs around that position.